# Index.jsx doesn't rerender on state change

Tags: reactjs, state, render, store

I use `react-translated` as translation provider for my React app, and the `index.jsx` `render` method is:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
    <TranslationProvider language={store.getState().language} translation={translation}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Routes/>
            </ Provider>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </TranslationProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Then, I update language on global state via dispatching actions...it works (language changes) but this `render` doesn't invoke again, and text  in my app doesn't switch to other language. Shouldn't it rerender whenever `state` changes in `store`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use componentlifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` to listen to state changes are call setstate if there is props change.

For example

```
this.state ={
    language: 'defaultlanguage'
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.language !== this.state.props){
       this.setState({
           language: nextProps.language
       }) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but where to put that code? Components don't receive language via props...
In components, I use: 
`<Translate text="app.button.home" />`  component where `app.button.home` is key defined in translations data file.